# Owin Cors Error

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, owin

Getting the following Error from code shown on in Startup.cs

```
'Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions' does not match any known middleware pattern
```

From:

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app){

        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        ConfigureOAuth(app);
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you are using the right "using" in top of your Startup class, this is an extension method won't build if you are not importing the correct library.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `app.UseCors()` not just `app.Use()`. Also, depending on what you want to do `app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll)` enables CORS for *all* cross-origins requests to your site.

Use

```
 var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(...);
 config.EnableCors(cors);
```

if you want to enable CORS for Web Api only

Comment: it was app.UseCors() that was a typo.